# Definite integral of Hypergeometric function 2F1

Tags: definite-integrals, special-functions, hypergeometric-function

I am looking for a way to evaluate

$
\mathcal{I}(z,x)=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{s^{ix}(1-s)^{-ix}}{\sqrt{s(1-s)t(1-t)}} \,_2F_1\left(
\frac{1}{2},1
; \frac{3}{2}
;
z^2 \,s^{1+2ix}(1-s)^{1-2ix} t(1-t)
\right)
$

where $x\geq0$ in closed form.

For $x=0$, I know that this integral evaluates to

$
\mathcal{I}(z,0)=\int_0^1 \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{s(1-s)t(1-t)}} \,_2F_1\left(
\frac{1}{2},1
; \frac{3}{2}
;
z^2 \,s(1-s) t(1-t)
\right)
=
\frac{1}{z^2}\sum_{j\geq1} \frac{z^2j}{2j-1}Beta\left(j-\frac{1}{2},j-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2
=
\pi^2 \,_3F_2\left(
\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}
;1, \frac{3}{2}
;
\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^2 
\right)$

(This is found by using the integral representation of Beta functions and the series-expression for the hypergeometric function, and then mathematica evaluates the sum straight away), but this approach doesn't seem to work when $x\neq 0$. Therefore, I am looking for a way to see this straight from the integral which might be easier to generalise..?

So, can anyone help me with a good way to see why the above holds without using the infinite sum, (or, in the best possible scenario, help me with the general $\mathcal{I}(z,x)$)?

The approaches I have tried so far include looking for cleaver changes of variables in the integral, and/or using the integral representation of

$\,_3F_2\left(
\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}
;1, \frac{3}{2}
;
\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^2 
\right)
\propto
\int_{0}^1 
u^{1/2-1}(1-u)^{1-1/2-1}
\,_2F_1\left(
\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}
; \frac{3}{2}
;
\left(\frac{z}{4}\right)^2 u 
\right)
du
$

but then I'm stuck. I know the hypergeometric functions have many nice properties, but I don't see how I can map this single integral to the double integral above, with the change of the parameter as well?

Comment: Have you checked whether using the Mellin–Barnes representation of $_2F_1$ and integrating out $s$ and $t$ gives a Fox H-function?

Comment: No, I haven't, thanks for the tip! If you could give me some more hints/details, that'd be very much appreciated!

Comment: Thank you again for your hint, this allowed me to rewrite the integral, via an infinite sum of gamma functions, as a [Fox-Wright function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fox%E2%80%93Wright_function), which also works for non-vanishing x. Thanks!

Comment: @Lou What about the variable $z$? Is it a real or complex number? Does it satisfy any inequalities or conditions? Such info could help avoid a lot of annoying casework...

Comment: @DavidH Yes, z>0, but what I'm really interested in is really the asymptotics at exponentially large z (the analytic continuation). I'm now trying to get it from the asymptotics of the Fox-Wright functions, but if you know a better way it would be highly appreciated!